# Use UTF-8 charset in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, utf-8, utf-16

I use the following in a script:

```
var JSONResult = Maps.newGeocoder().geocode(member.address);
var AddressFormatted= JSONResult.results[0].formatted_address;
```

and the result sometimes look like

> Rue de Cognel��e

I would like to force to have the result in UTF-8 charset.
How can I do that ?

Vincent

Comment: maybe this [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_geocoder#setLanguage) is relevant ?

Comment: In the future please use more descriptive question titles.

Answer (score 6):

You can do charset conversions using Blobs. This example converts "foo" from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

```
Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString("foo", "UTF-8").getDataAsString("UTF-16")
```