# JDBC to mysql Character encoding

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

Ok so i'll demonstrate my problem on tutorial code from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc

```
function insert() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<instance>", "user", "password");

  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into person (lname,fname) values (?,?)");
  var start = new Date();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    // Objects are accessed using 1-based indexing
    stmt.setObject(1, 'firstName' + i);
    stmt.setObject(2, 'lastName' + i);
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
  var res = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
  var endTime = new Date();
  Logger.log("time is " + (endTime.getTime() - start.getTime()) + "ms");
  Logger.log("res has " + res.length);
}
```

Im from slovakia and we have special characters like žťščľýá after i change this line

```
stmt.setObject(1, 'firstName' + i);
```

to

```
stmt.setObject(1, 'žťščľýá' + i);
```

I'll get ???? in my db.I have utf8_general_ci in my db and my table
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HPp9.png)

I've seen this [JDBC Service with MySQL : UTF-8 encoding / decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914545/jdbc-service-with-mysql-utf-8-encoding-decoding) and tried `Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString("foo", "UTF-8").getDataAsString("UTF-16")` also this [JDBC character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040597/jdbc-character-encoding) where lot of people are suggesting to use `?characterEncoding=utf8` after my connection link but i'll get error message.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully able to write to [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc#accessing_google_cloud_sql_databases) (MySQL 5.5) using the characters you have there. That is the only MySQL DB that I have access to.

You an see that a simple table I have called animals get the right data in it. I even tried Japanese and it worked well.

[image]

Here is the code I used -

```
function writeEncodingIssue() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://<MY_INTSANCE_NAME>/mysql");
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into animals (name) values (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    stmt.setObject(1, 'žťščľýá' + i);//ショッピング
    stmt.addBatch();
  }
  var res = stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  conn.close();
}
```

Perhaps you can try to write a test program in Java or something else to isolate this to an Apps Script issue?

EDIT: I've bee able to reproduce this issue with MySQL. The [issue tracker item](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2674) has been updated. The Apps Script team is investigating this.